# Not able to add image using pug js

Tags: html, image, pug

I am using pug js as my template engine and tried adding an image to my page but it wouldn't show the image and shows the alt text instead. My layout.pug is in the views directory and the image which I tried using is in the public/images directory.

[image: This is the directory structure.]

And this is the pug code

```
footer
  p
    | Made by Lakshya
    a(href='')
      img(src='../public/images/GitHub-Mark-Light-32px.png', alt='Github Logo')
```

Comment: Try deleting `../public` and have your src start with `/images/`. "public" directory is generally the root. And if that doesn't work, load it up in your browser and inspect the HTML -- the problem isn't with pug, but either your server isn't set up right to serve the content, or the output HTML is wrong. Paste the full path into your browser address bar and see if it actually loads.

Comment: Thank you it worked when I started the path with /images/. But why didn't it work when I started the path with public?

Comment: Why would it? The server root *is* the public dir, you can't go any 'higher' than that. If you could, it would be a huge security risk because anyone could access your entire computer by hacking the URL.